# How Do I Connect Angular 9 App To API On My Localhost

Tags: angular, api, localhost

I have the following API running on my Windows 10 localhost
http://localhost:8012/api/employee

.Net Core API. I have included CORS code in the API that works when I connect via a .Net desktop client

Which returns
[
{
"id": 100,
"fName": "Carl",
"lName": "Rodgers",
"email": "crodgers@xyzcorp.com",
"ssn": "111223333"
}
]

etc ...

In my Angular service class

```
getEmployees(): Observable<Employee[]> {
    return this.http.get<Employee[]>(this.employeesUrl);
}
```

Using Chrome below is what I get in the console

Angular is running in the development mode. Call enableProdMode() to enable the production mode.
client:52 [WDS] Live Reloading enabled.

Any suggestions? I've tried everything. Not even sure where to look now to troubleshoot.

Comment: So... what's the actual problem?

Comment: development mode is enabled for you to easier catch change detection problems and also it exposes debug information of your components. it is fine that this message appears. if you try to `ng serve --prod` the message will disappear but it has nothing in common with http request you provided. problem in the question is unclear

Comment: In Chrome, watch the "Network" tab. The API call will appear there. You will be able to see if it responded or not. Are you subscribed to the api call in Angular? Is the problem in the subscription? It's not clear what your issue is. As `Andrei` said, the `enableProdMode()` is expected for angular running in dev mode. It has nothing to do with an API call.

Comment: export class EmployeeListComponent implements OnInit {
  employees: Employee[];

  constructor(private backendService: BackendApiService) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.backendService.getEmployees().subscribe((employees) => {
      this.employees = employees;
    });
  }

Comment: I believe my Angular code is correct. My EmployeeListComponent calls the Service component.  The code works when I hard-coded data in the Service component.  The API returns good JSON in Postman. I figured it was CORS or something 'simple' that I have overlooked